# Azure Download Cost data pipeline failing with no error? for Azure DevOps Cost Insights dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

I'm using Azure DevOps and I have got this Azure Cost Insights package from the marketplace to have a graph on my Azure DevOps dashboard.

In order for it to work, I need to make a build pipeline to get the cost data from Azure.

I've made an empty repository, initialized it and I've build a pipeline without YML and added 2 tasks predefined: Download Cost data and Publish Cost data.

I have configured the download cost data as per my subscription using:

- locale: en-US
- currency: GBP
- regio info: GB
- OfferID: MS-AZR-0003P (pay as you go)

But the whole task fails without any error:

```
unhandled exception during Download Task { Error: ""
at o.pipeline.e (D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>\1.0.30\index.js:245:1126571)
at s (D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>\1.0.30\index.js:245:110551)
at s (D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>\1.0.30\index.js:127:27863)
at D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>\1.0.30\index.js:127:29103
at o (D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>\1.0.30\index.js:161:7037)
at D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>5\1.0.30\index.js:127:26784
at B.t.headersOnly.t.streamedResponse.t.body.function.t.body.pipe.a [as _callback] (D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>\1.0.30\index.js:1:299338)
at B.t._callback.t.callback.t.callback [as callback] (D:\a\_tasks\DownloadCostData_<identifying_info_Ithink>\1.0.30\index.js:221:5503)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at B.emit (events.js:191:7)
statusCode: 302,
```